# VBA Excel Percent format in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Is there a way to save a specific format in an array?  I'm trying to find the percent difference and the regular difference between numbers in two separate grids.  I can do these things individually but when I try to put the answer in the same worksheet I run into errors.

As of now, I calculate the percent difference and then I select the grid where all my answers are and change the style and number format.  However, when I try to show the difference as well (such as "percent difference / difference" the program returns a long decimal for the percent difference.  I know that the reason is because the number format and style format are not saved into the actual array but I can't figure out how to fix it.

I've tried the following:

- Changing the format right before I create the slash and the difference
- Assigning the answer array to the current values in the active cell (the values are still the decimals, not the percent counterparts)
- Calculating percent difference and the difference, then changing the format (this was more of a faint hope than an actual attempt to change anything)

I can't remember if I tried anything else but I know it failed horribly.

***** Example ******

The user will send my program to a specific workbook that has two sheets with a grid of numbers on them.  These grids have the exact same dimensions.  My program will calculate the difference between these sheets (Sheet1 - Sheet2), the percent difference ((Sheet1 - Sheet2) / Sheet2), and both.  These three calculations are presented on three separate sheets that the program creates.  All of the numbers that the program produces will be in the cells that correspond to the cells where it got the numbers in the first place.  Also, the third sheet (both percent and difference) are seen as "percent difference / difference".  Now here's an example with test numbers.

Grid 1

```
12.0    5.0

2.0     10.0
```

Grid 2

```
6.0     7.0

1.0     3.0
```

Diff

```
6.0     -2.0

1.0     7.0
```

Percent Diff

```
100.00%     -28.57%

100.00%     233.33%
```

So the "Both" tab would look like:

```
100.00%/6.0     -28.57/-2.0

100.00%/1.0     233.33%/7.0
```

Sorry for not making this more grid like.  I wasn't sure how to present it.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds as if you are exporting the array and the string for each item is a percentage value, followed by a '/' and then the value is that what you mean? e.g. ".05%/25" Are you trying to store these as values that can still be used in calculations as well as presenting them combined?

Comment: Please show us an example so we don't have to guess what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I added an edit, sorry the grids look a bit weird in the example but pretty much if there's a space then it's in a different cell.  Thank you for responding

Comment: @datatoo The values of difference and percent difference are going to be presented both separately and together.  This is so the user can see specific numbers without too much clutter or, if they need, they can see how the percent and the difference look easily (ex. if there's a huge difference but a small percent then that means they're dealing with gigantic numbers).  As of now we are not doing calculations on these later

Comment: "Sorry for not making this more grid like. I wasn't sure how to present it." Mark it as `code`. That gives you a fixed-size font so you can adjust column width with spaces or whatever.

Comment: @Jean Thanks for the tip, we can all at least tell which numbers are in column 1 and which are in column 2 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I completely follow, but I think you may just need the range object ".Text" method:

```
 dim rgNumValues as Range    ' cells formatted as 12.0, 5.0 etc
 dim rgPctValues as Range    ' cells formatted as 100%, -28.57% etc.
```

Then to create new cells that marry both formats

```
 dim rgNumAndPct as Range

 rgNumAndPct.Cells(1,1) = rgNumValues.Cells(1,1).Text + " / " _
                        + rgPctValues.Cells(1,1).Text

 ' creates cells w string values like "12.0 / 100%", "5.0 / -28.57%" etc.
```

The ".Text" method extracts the visible string from your NumValues and PctValues rather than the underlying numeric value.  Just rewrite as a loop to do all the cells.  For a very large range, you can speed up by creating NumAndPct values in a variant array and assigning the array to the target range.

Comment: just not clear in the question how the array numbers are derived

Comment: Thank you very much, it did what I wanted it to but I still have a question.  The user input what cell the data starts in (for example "B2") so I set the range sizes from B2 to the end of the grid.  When I ran the code though, it started from C3.  I decided to initialize the ranges to A1 and all the grids were correct (started at B2).  Are ranges created differently?

Comment: Note quite sure what you mean without seeing your code. But here's a debugging tip that might make it easier to figure out a range variable called "rg" that is misbehaving. Put this stmt in your loop: [rg.Worksheet.Parent.Activate: rg.Worksheet.Activate: rg.Select: Stop]. Then as you hit f5 repeatetly you'll get a visual picture of what's going on. (You can shorten that stmt if you know that the range variable is always within the active workbook or active sheet.)

Comment: That helped out greatly, thanks.  When I did the select my range turned out to be from A1 to the end of my grid.  I just initialized all of my ranges to start at A1 and it's worked for at least two different tests.  Thanks again =D

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this with code in vba you would use the Format function for each item and append the cells in a similar fashion.  If a simple formulaic version would work, something like this, substituting the sheet names in where needed.

[image]